# How to create timer with handler

Tags: android, kotlin, handler, runnable

Need to create stopwatch in android, for now I'v got somethink like this, simple function to start counting and display time, but i dont know what am I doing wrong with postdelayed:

```
fun runTimer() {
        val timeView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.time_view)
        val handler = Handler()
        handler.post(Runnable {
            var hours = seconds / 3600
            var minutes = (seconds % 3600) / 60
            var secs = seconds % 60
            var time = String.format("%d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, secs)
            timeView.setText(time)
            if (running) {
                seconds++
            }
            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000)
        })
    }
```

what exactly should i put instead of this? (need to be runnable type)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe in your use case the most suitable solution would be to use a Chronometer - you can read more about it [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Chronometer). Also if you want to watch a video tutorial you can check this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RLnb4vVkftc). Hope this helps. Additionally if you want to have the functionality to be able to set a specific time frame and countdown using a CountDownTimer is a good option - [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer)

Answer (score 0):

I use handler as Timer like this :

```
class TimerClass {

fun startTimer( handler : Handler ,
                   stuffToDo : () -> Unit ,
                   stopTimeInSeconds : Int ,
                   timePassed : Int ,
                   interval : Long){

    handler.postDelayed( {

        stuffToDo.invoke()
        if (timePassed < stopTimeInSeconds){
            startTimer(handler ,
                stuffToDo ,
                stopTimeInSeconds ,
                timePassed + 1 ,
                interval)
        }

    } , interval)

}}
```

then to use it :

```
   val time = TestClass()

    time.startTimer(handler = Handler() ,
        stuffToDo = { textView.text = "some new text" } ,
        stopTimeInSeconds = 5 ,
        timePassed = 0 , 
        interval = 1000)
```

So you define a method in the class , and provide all dependencies(objects) and injecting to it, you are creating the operation you want to do as a lambda function. then call the handler delayed method and in the handler if the criteria (if statement) is true you will call the method itself recursively with an increment (timePassed+1).
Now you have a working timer.